# Error using AJAX with symfony to filter a section by category

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony, twig

Im using AJAX (Or triying) to filter a section of movies by category, here is the Jquery code im using:

```
$(function(){

 $('.Action').click(function(e){
    $("#moviesContainer").html("Loading movies...");
    $.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data) {
    $('#moviesContainer').html(data);
    e.preventDefault();
 });
 return false;
});
});
```

And the controller:

```
/**
 * @Route(path="/show/category/{category}", name="aflam_movie_show")
 * @Template("MoviesBundle:Default:allmovies.html.twig")
 */
public function showMovieByCategoryAction(Request $request, $category)
{
    $em    = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $dql   = "SELECT a FROM MoviesBundle:Movie a WHERE a.category=" .$category." ORDER BY a.created DESC";
    $query = $em->createQuery($dql);

    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $query, /* query NOT result */
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1)/*page number*/,
        5/*limit per page*/
    );

    $pagination->setUsedRoute('aflam_movie_show');

    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
        return array('pagination' => $pagination);
    }
}
```

And Im setting the path in the buttom like this:

```
{% for videocategory in ['Action','Drama','Comedy','Anime','Adults'] %}
   <p class="lead"><a class="{{videocategory}}" href={{path('aflam_movie_show',{category:videocategory})}}">{{videocategory}}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

When I click the buttom it only show "Loading movies...", what's the problem? Its my first time making an AJAX call with symfony so Im kinda lost.

Answer (score 1):

Just an important note to complete the given answer.

When you deal with AJAX, you must work with the browser network/console opened, in addition of the Symfony profiler at the Request tab.

i.e :

[image: Network]

[image: Profiler]

By doing this, in case of error, you will be able to understand the error and so be able to fix it (given message containing the file and line that causes the problem).

In your case, the error is surely about the missing response in your controller action.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the browser's network tab and see what response your request gave. My guess is

```
 return array('pagination' => $pagination);
```

should be

```
 return new Response(array('pagination' => $pagination));
```

Since Controllers must return a response.

Also move your query into a Repository Class.